# set css active class for current menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

i try to write a function to set current active for menu but my menu has 2 field need

class="current" and class="current selectedLava"

my menu:

```
<nav>
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="About.aspx">Home Cinema</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Home_Movie.aspx">Movie</a>
        <ul>
            <li ><a href="List_Movie.aspx">List Movie</a></li>
            <li ><a href="abc.aspx">List</a></li>
    </li>

</ul><!-- end menu -->
```

i mean when i visit Home_Movie.aspx, it will be

```
        <li class="current selectedLava"><a href="Home_Movie.aspx">Movie</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="List_Movie.aspx">List Movie</a></li>
            <li ><a href="abc.aspx">List</a></li>
    </li>
```

and when i visit List_Movie.aspx, it will be

```
        <li class="current selectedLava"><a href="Home_Movie.aspx">Movie</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="List_Movie.aspx">List Movie</a></li>
            <li ><a href="abc.aspx">List</a></li>
    </li>
```

easy for you to understand:

1: http://s30.postimg.org/cx4ks87y9/image.png

2: http://s30.postimg.org/p09wfsj0h/image.png

Comment: Can you try to reproduce your issue in http://jsfiddle.net/ so that it would be easier for us to help ?

Comment: What's role of class "selectedLava"?

Comment: hi idlerboris, what you mean, i couldnt got you.
sorry, my eng not good :(

Comment: Do it for well http://dotnet--solutions.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2013-06-08T02:27:00-07:00&max-results=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you replace your highlightActiveMenuItem method to this:

```
highlightActiveMenuItem = function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname.substr(6);    
    $('nav li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('current');
    if ($('nav li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().parent().hasClass('sf-menu'))
    {
      $('nav li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('selectedLava');
    }
    else
    {
      $('nav li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().parent().parent().addClass('current selectedLava');  
    }
}
```

Or use specific class for item of top-level menu to avoid triple `parent()`

Comment: thank you, if they visit the page bellow, how can i set for class="current selectedLava"

Comment: @KevinHuynh, are you want add 2 classes? Use `.addClass('current selectedLava')`

Comment: can you explain more clear, yeah i want to add to both 2 class

Comment: If you want add 2 class to `li`, then use following `$('nav li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('current selectedLava');`

Comment: @KevinHuynh, I updated my answer. If I correctly understand your question, then this will be work

Comment: thank you but it not work
i dont know how to debug it :( sorry

Comment: @KevinHuynh can you explain, what element on form must have class `current`? And what element must have class `selectedLava`?

Comment: yes, when you visit a page, Home_Movie.aspx the class for it will be current and the parent will be current selectedLava
i understand your code but i dont know why it not work :|

Comment: well, thank you idlerboris so much :)
i updated my question, now you can easy to understand :D

Comment: @KevinHuynh, I think my last answer was incorrect for active top-level menu. Fix.

Comment: Why class `current` dissapear? I fix one little thing - remove dot in function `hasClass`

Comment: yes, i couldnt understand what happen T.T
after fix same as your last answer they show the same as s15.postimg.org/hhlmh29az/image.png

Comment: You lost close tag of `ul` in your code in question. Maybe problem in this. And try delete your browser cache.

Comment: i try to move
   if ($('nav li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().parent().hasClass('sf-menu'))
    {
      $('nav li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('current selectedLava');
    }
and very suprise :| and they are the same, i try in 2 browse T.T maybe now will with IE

Comment: i update the code in my question above, you can see, is that right?

Comment: But click function used only for example. If I correctly understand your question, you must use `var url = window.location.pathname;` and remove click function. Is it works for you?

Comment: the class current in the first disappear again, i dont know why :( try to search

Comment: Maybe you need use `var url = window.location.pathname.replace("/", "");`?

Comment: thank you, maybe i know why
i use a temple receive from my brother, they already has a jquery function to auto check for SelectedLava, i try to modify it right now :) 
sorry, i wasted your time :)

Comment: finally, i found the mistake
they get the url not right :) thank you idlerboris, i updated my answer